# Spring session returning different session IDs during and after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I have an application that's using both Spring Security and Spring Session. I'm converting my application to store its Spring Sessions in MySQL using the XML jdbc configuration, and that appears to be working, as the session records are appearing in the MySQL table.

For other reasons, I am using an internally created session object in conjunction with the spring session objects, and attempting to use the spring session ID to link the two sessions. Here is the basic problem I'm running into:

First I authenticate, and a spring session is created.
This gives me Spring Session ID A, which I store in my internal session table to link to the spring session.
Other filters are hit, and the request makes its way to the REST controller.
In the REST controller, I try to access the spring session, and I see a valid ID and spring session, but with Spring Session ID B, thus the connection between the spring session and my internal session is broken.

Is there a reason I would have 2 separate authenticated spring sessions with the same principal information in the sessions?

Separate but related question, if I try to access the spring session ID via the RequestContextHolder, it gives an ID in standard all-caps hex code format (e.g. 3AD475F78823D7CDC5C4571D50B0AB35) whereas if I access it via the SecurityContextHolder, the ID is in a different format (e.g. c2215820-bd08-4c78-b26e-0821913333a1), is there a particular reason for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DefaultCookieSerializer.setUseBase64Encoding(). The value set on the cookie is base64 encoded by default. You can base64 decode the 3AD475F78823D7CDC5C4571D50B0AB35 and you'll get the value of the session id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

to protect from session fixation Spring Security by default gives you a new session after authentication, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session#session-fixation

Please let me know if this is usefull.

-Kaj :)

Comment: Interesting, I'll check through the logs, it sounds like it should have a session destroyed message somewhere if that's the case. I'll poke around and update, thanks!

Comment: @JoeD Good! Please let me know how this works out for you :)

Comment: Not currently finding any session destroyed messages/events. Still confused as to why there is a difference in formats between the spring session IDs, as I mentioned above.